# There are any difference in performance having a dictionary object of images?

Tags: image, performance, react-native, object

I want to manage all static resources in my React Native project in the best and mantainable way.

I'm using `Image` component, and all of this is for passing the local reference of the image, like `<Image source={imageReference}` />, where `imageReference` can be get in the next two ways.

I have this:

```
import mailIcon     from '../../../assets/icons/mail.png';
import passwordIcon from '../../../assets/icons/password.png';
import mainLogo     from '../../../assets/brand/main-logo.png';
```

but also have this:

*`index.js` in the assets folder*

```
export const brand = {
  mainLogo: require('./brand/main-logo.png'),
  logoHorBlanco: require('./brand/logo-hor-blanco.png'),
};

export const icons = {
  checked: require('./icons/checked.png'),
  unchecked: require('./icons/unchecked.png'),
};
```

`SomeComponent.js` in somewhere

```
import { brand }       from '../../assets';
```

The first way allow me to import only the images that I needed, but is dificult to mantain the paths. The second way, is exported from the `assets` folder, so when I need an images I just import the right object and use the image that I need with `brand.mainLogo` (for example).

So I want to know:

1. If there are differences in performance between the two options.
2. When im importing the `brand` object for example, are (in some way) imported (or required, or cached, or something) all images in that object, o just the one that I call with `brand.mainLogo`.

Thanks.